# iRate in Button Click event

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, rate

I am using IRate in my ios application.

I had coped two classes of iRate in my code. This is my code in appDelegate

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    //set the bundle ID. normally you wouldn't need to do this
    //as it is picked up automatically from your Info.plist file
    //but we want to test with an app that's actually on the store
    [iRate sharedInstance].applicationBundleID = @"com.s.s";
    [iRate sharedInstance].onlyPromptIfLatestVersion = NO;

    //enable preview mode
    [iRate sharedInstance].previewMode = NO;
    //[iRate sharedInstance].daysUntilPrompt = 5;
    //[iRate sharedInstance].usesUntilPrompt = 15;
}
```

But by this the promt can only come at start of app.

I want to open it in button click.

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lead the user to appstore and review your app directly. Add this line to your button click action:

```
[[iRate sharedInstance] openRatingsPageInAppStore];
```

Comment: Is your app already on the app store? If not, a connection error is the only thing what you can get. If it is already an appstore app, there might be something wrong with your setting for iRate.